# Make page move down when clicking Navbar-Toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm making an Website so I can practice my Web Skills but I've run into a problem. The problem is when the Web Page is on a Mobile for example the Navbar collapse so it fits on the device but when they click the Navbar-Toggle button the Links come over the top of the header I have and I don't want this to happen. What I want to happen is when they click it, it moves all the elements down if you understand what I mean.

If you don't go to this website -> www.thestartupguys.co.uk <- and shrink the page until it become where you have to toggle the navbar and then toggle it and you see the header-image move down.

[Standard CSS](http://pastebin.com/aRGzRCAT)
[Custom CSS](http://pastebin.com/tZbRYVLb)

Comment: Can you share you code, so we can help you better?

Comment: Show me your code, please. Cannot say much without seeing what you've tried so far.

Comment: What you're trying to do is the default behavior of a Bootstrap navbar unless you have added CSS rules or are using a fixed position nav. You need to post your code (HTML/CSS/JS) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay I can post all my code I use the default bootstrap and a framework and then custom stuff with my own css

Comment: I've updated the links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These rules are causing it: See working example.

Remove height: 50 and margin-top: 20px

```
.navbar-brand img,
.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Remove height: 90px

```
.navbar-default {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);

/*!
Main Page CSS || Created By Stephen Hinett | Crafted-Solutions
 */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*
 
* BASIC STYLE
- Headers and Paragraphs
 
* GLOBAL STYLE
- Navbar
- Header
 
*/

/*===========================================================================================*/

/* Headings & Paragraphs ------------------------- */

/*===========================================================================================*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif, serif;
  color: #474747;
}
p {
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif, serif;
}
/*===========================================================================================*/

/* Navbar ------------------------- */

/*===========================================================================================*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand img,
.navbar-nav {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 50px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*===========================================================================================*/

/* Header ------------------------- */

/*=
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">Something</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir you are great help, thanks a lot you made it work. Removing the Height : 90px from the Navbar-default made it work how I wanted thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome and please mark you're question as answered so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace This CSS

```
nav.mobile_menu {
background-color: #fff;
display: none;
float: left;
left: -15px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 15px;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
top: 100px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: I tried adding this but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks for the help thought